Compile typescript without module export/import declarations
I'm writing a number of functions in Typescript, to be then compiled into JavaScript and used in Google-App-Script. They're stored in separate files, with some imported into one another. I'd like the compiled JavaScript files to not have any of the import/export syntax because GAS does not need them (and will throw syntax errors) as GAS scripts have all functions and vars globally hoisted.
A usual file looks like this:
import { foo } from 'bar';

export function exampleFunction(input: string) {
    foo(input);
}

I'd like my compiled javascript files to look like:
function exampleFunction(input) {
    foo(input);
}

What tsconfig.json settings would allow the compilation as I've described? Or is this something I would need to write a script for, after compilation.
I tested the "module": "none" settings, however that disallows all import/export statements inside of the Typescript code.

In the end do you want javascript? Or typescript? Because you say you want javascript, but your desired output has a type annotation.

Also, what are you doing that different how the documentation recommends using typescript?

@AlexWayne Yes I want javascript. The documentation you provided suggests using clasp to upload the typescript to the cloud, however I would like this to be done locally.

you need to do something like:
import { type foo as Foo } from 'bar';

declare var foo: Foo;

function exampleFunction(input: string) {
    foo(input);
}

And module option in tsconfig.json as  preserve.

This would cause an error, as either I use foo, which has no definition and wouldn't do what I want, or because there are multiple functions called foo, one declared in this file, and another from 'bar' which would have the actual implementation of foo.
